# How can i configure urls that yslow monitor?

Tags: performance, selenium, config, yslow, pagespeed

I have YSlow and ShowSlow and pagespeed integrated into our continuous build in a way that when tests are run, yslow will pass metrics like pageload time, pageweight etc to the Showslow server which in turn displays the result graphically. I currently have this setup working but I still dont know how to configure which urls YSlow will monitor and send info for. Any answers?? For example I will like to monitor these pages in an ecommerce site:

Home page
Books main
Product
ISBN
Search Works
Detail

how can i tell YSlow whenever you hit a url that matches any of the above collect the result and send ova to ShowSlow?? Hopefully my question is clear. thahks guys

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) service. It's excellent and it's free.